# Sinch Verification does not send a verification code in Test Flight from iTunes connect even though it worked in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, app-store, sinch

I used cocoa pods so I never downloaded the Sinch Verification SDK.

the following is my pod file:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'krush' do
 # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!

pod ‘Firebase’
pod ‘FirebaseDatabase’
pod 'FirebaseAuth'
pod ‘Firebase/Auth’

  # Pods for krush

pod ‘SinchVerification-Swift’

end
```

I did not include bit code  when uploading. I do see some steps about embedded binaries for frameworks ect. but I assume I do not need to use these since I used cocoa pods. Anyway my question is why can't I receive verification from test flight version ?

Comment: ARe you getting an error message? if so what?

Comment: ok i think my initial understanding was wrong. It just isn't working anywhere since I changed bundle id in order to upload to App Store. I tried re installing cocoa pods but it did not work. I am not getting an error message but I assume there is somewhere I have to change bundle id but I do not see it in cocoa pods or on the sinch dashboard

Comment: i actually have received a few verification codes but not as many as were sent and they took like half an hour at least. IT certainly is not working reliably and I am not even sure when these codes are from. I still think that changing the name is this issue

Comment: I keep getting old verification codes. is it possible that they are sending despite the name change but are for some reason very very delayed? If so how can either of these issues be fixed?

Comment: Did you change the project name? If so have you checked your cocoapod file for project name?

Comment: What country are you sending to?

Comment: i changed the bundle id. but i don't see a spot in the cocoa pod file above for project name? I am sending to canada and everyday up until today it worked great but today i thought nothing was set but received like 20 verification codes hours later

Comment: it is working perfectly fine again without changing the bundle name! perhaps the server was just slow for some reason